# Mono on Apache on OSX: how do I resolve this desktop mutex error?

Tags: macos, apache, mono, mod-mono

I'm running Apache 2.2.26 on OSX 10.9.3, and until recently, I had finally successfully installed Mono so I can host ASP.NET pages on this box.

But suddenly, I'm getting 404 errors for every ASPX page I try to access. The exception seems to be occurring in System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.AssertVirtualPathExists, and the Apache error log has this rather obtuse error:

[crit] (2)No such file or directory: Failed to initialize the dashboard mutex '/tmp/mod_mono_dashboard_XXGLOBAL_1.lock' in child process
The temp path above does not exist, there's just a file named mod_mono_server_global and another named mod_mono_server_global_blah (where "blah" is a random number) in the /tmp folder.

The only thing I can think of that I've done in the past month (the last time I played with ASP.NET) is to lock down permissions in /Library/WebServer/Documents/. Still, the ASPX test file I'm using has my user account as the owner, _www as the group, and permissions are set to 755. The mod_mono_server4.exe process is running under the _www account (as does Apache), and user _www is of course in the _www group.

Any ideas?

*(I already asked on ServerFault, but the snobs there don't answer questions for anything but professional servers, and this is a home-based personal box.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, either a recent reboot fixed it, or the upgrade to 10.9.4 that happened with said reboot.